# When to acknowledge funding

Tags: mathematics, funding, reference-request

I got a funding from the DFG called "Eigene Stelle". My question is whether I have to acknowledge funding in every article I write or just in the articles that are related to the projects in my proposal for the funding?

I think that it is enough to acknowledge funding only in articles related to the proposal but I am not really sure and found no reliable source for that.

Comment: Since the DFG fully funds your own salary, I would think it should be acknowledged in every paper written during the time you hold that position. But I don't have a source for that.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, funders require acknowledgement in every article that was supported by their funding.

So, what's actually getting supported by the funding?

- If you're a professor or researcher with multiple sources of support, then you are generally expected to account your time to each supporting project separately.  So if you're supported 10% by a project, you only put 10% of your hours on that project, and only the things you actually do with that time get acknowledgement---i.e., publications related to the specific project.
- If you're a graduate student or postdoc, however, you'll often have only one source of funding that supports both your work on the project and your continuing professional development in general.  In that case, you put the acknowledgement on everything, because it's all being supported by the same funding, whether or not it has anything to do with the original proposal.

Note that what's really important here is the accounting, not the position or the proposal.  If funding supports you in create a publication, that funding must be credited, whether or not it's within the expected scope of the project.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. However, Im looking for a reference specifically for my situation with a DFG funding "eigene stelle".

Comment: @Mare Why would it be different for that funding source?

Comment: @BryanKrause Who knows. Im just looking for a reference to be sure.

Comment: @Mare I've attempted to add clarification.  In determining acknowledgement  only matters how you account for your support, not whether what you've done with it matches what you were expected to do.  Whether doing unexpected things is a problem or not is an entirely different question...

Comment: If you need confirmation about your specific grant, just ask the DFG (instead of random stangers on the internet).

Comment: @mmeent I thought that tthis information must be available somewhere on the internet and I just cant find it...